# Jquery Closest From Element Value

Tags: jquery, input, closest

Im trying to get a form element value using closest. Here some example code.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Hour <input type="input" value="12" name="data[hour]" class="hour" /></td>
    <td>Minute <input type="input" value="12" name="data[minute]" class="minute" /></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="add-data">Add Row</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

See I cant serialize the form because it is part of a large form so I need to grab each input closest to the add row link as yo will be able to add multiple rows.

I have tried

```
var hour = $(this).closest('.hour').val();    
var hour = $(this).closest('input', '.hour').val();
var hour = $(this).closest('input[name="data[hour]]").val();
```

Any ideas how I can get the form values ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you have just one `.hour` element per tr, this will do it:

```
var hour = $(this).closest('tr').find('.hour').val();
```

[`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) will:

> Get the first ancestor element that
>   matches the selector, beginning at the
>   current element and progressing up
>   through the DOM tree.

So, you need to go up to the tr, and from there find the `.hour` descendant.

Comment: Thats the one perfect.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Karim79's answer:

.closest() moves up the DOM tree until it finds a match. It will not work with elements at the same level - such as in your case (all elements have a td as a parent) .

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

To use closest() in your situation, you'd have to use (which is a bit of overkill here):

```
$(this).closest("tr").find(".hour").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".addToCart").on('click', function() {
  var item_id = $(this).closest('div').find('#item_id').val();
  var labtest_id = $(this).closest('div').find('#labtest_id').val();
  var vendor_id = $(this).closest('div').find('#vendor_id').val();

  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: You should add explanation.